# UICollectionView with pagination. Keeping the second cell in center of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS.

I am having my collection view inside tableview cell.
There are 3 cells in collection view cell.

I need to show the second cell of collection view in center of the screen as shown in the image and also want to add pagination into it.
Any help will be appreciated.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaDNW.png)
Thank You

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently using that you are stuck with, for people to help you out with?

Answer (score -1):

I had to do a similar collection view a few months ago, This is the code that I use:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let layout = theNameOfYourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing // Calculate cell size
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let index = (offset + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing // Calculate the cell need to be center

        if velocity.x > 0 { // Scroll to -->
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: ceil(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.right, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        } else if velocity.x < 0 { // Scroll to <---
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: floor(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        } else if velocity.x == 0 { // No dragging
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: round(index) * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        }
    }
```

This code calculates the size of your cell, how many cells have already been shown and once the scroll is finished, adjust it to leave the cell centered.

Make sure you have the `pagingEnabled` of your collectionView in `false` if you want to use this code.

Also, implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`in your `ViewController`

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this documentation: 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate and 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619385-scrollviewwillenddragging